# ¿Cómo instalar coco en Python?

Tags: python

Quiero instalar coco en jupyter notebook, pero me da fallo. Ejecuto `pip install coco` y me sale el siguiente error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\theh4\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\theh4\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-db93p5t7\\coco\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\theh4\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-db93p5t7\\coco\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\theh4\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-mfglhbzm'
         cwd: C:\Users\theh4\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-db93p5t7\coco\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\theh4\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-db93p5t7\coco\setup.py", line 9, in <module>
        import coco
      File "C:\Users\theh4\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-db93p5t7\coco\coco.py", line 18, in <module>
        from docopt import docopt
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docopt'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Hola! Puedes colocar los logs generados? Si usas Windows deberían estar en `%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini` , si utilizas Mac o Linux puedes correr `pip install coco --log ./output.log`

Comment: Okay parece que falta una dependencia. Puedes instalarla manualmente utilizando `pip install docopt`

Comment: @GustavoSánchez Si era eso, lo que no entiendo es que lo he conseguido descarga pero a la hora de ejecutar  `import coco` me sale el siguiente error `No module named 'coco'
`

Comment: Quería ver su documentación pero parece que es una librería que ya no tiene soporte. Su última versión fue sacada el 2013: https://pypi.org/project/coco/ y tampoco parece haber mucha información acerca de su uso. Tal vez tengas que probar con otra librería similar.

Comment: En este caso diría que la librería se ha renombrado a [como](https://pypi.org/project/como/): https://pypi.org/project/como/